# build command using ng-build not working with @angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

ng-build is not working with @angular-cli although it works fine with @angular/cli

> Error - 
>   You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.

Comment: Have you navigated to the project folder after typing ng new [proj name]?
Otherwise it sounds like you may have the old angular-cli installed still. I would remove them both and re-install from npm.

Comment: won't build run with older versions of angular-cli?